# Tipsi-stripe error while running on expo managed workflow

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, expo

I am currently working on an Expo project (with managed workflow) that requires me to implement a payment function with Stripe. I am using tipsi-stripe to integrate Stripe on my app. While running the app I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'StripeModule.init')
```

Is there anything I can do to solve this error without ejecting expo?

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't lose anytime with Expo payments, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-stripe-client instead :D